# Error 400 on server: Could not find class docsf

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-foreman

I try to include the module [docsf](https://github.com/devopera/puppet-docsf) on my `Foreman/Puppet`-System. I cloned the git and moved the content to the modules-path `/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules`.

If I assign the module to a host, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class docsf for example.com on node example.com .
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

This is the tree of files (`/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules`):

```
docsf/
├── lib
│   └── facter
│       └── configserver_firewall.rb
├── LICENSE
├── manifests
│   ├── init.pp
│   ├── params.pp
│   ├── postinit.pp
│   └── preinit.pp
├── metadata.json
├── README.md
├── spec
│   └── spec_helper.rb
├── templates
│   ├── conf.maldet.erb
│   ├── csf.allow.erb
│   ├── csf.conf.erb
│   ├── csf.fignore.erb
│   ├── csf.ignore.erb
│   └── csf.pignore.erb
└── tests
    └── init.pp
```

This is the file-tree with permissions:

```
[root@puppet modules]# tree -p -u -g docsf/
docsf/
├── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  lib
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  facter
│       └── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  configserver_firewall.rb
├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  LICENSE
├── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  manifests
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  init.pp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  params.pp
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  postinit.pp
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  preinit.pp
├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  metadata.json
├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  README.md
├── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  spec
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  spec_helper.rb
├── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  templates
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  conf.maldet.erb
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  csf.allow.erb
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  csf.conf.erb
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  csf.fignore.erb
│   ├── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  csf.ignore.erb
│   └── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  csf.pignore.erb
└── [drwxr-xr-x puppet   root    ]  tests
    └── [-rw-r--r-- puppet   root    ]  init.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

Please produce the output of:

`cat docsf/manifests/init.pp`

Make sure the Content looks something like this:

`class docsf{`
`#ClassContent`
`}`

Comment: Maybe try making a tree under `/etc/puppet/modules/`